# Making DateTime column populate its own value on insert

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I am new to both .Net and EF.  In mysql I can define my database to autoinsert a timestamp in the date column.  I am trying to do the same thing in sqlexpress.

This is what I have for my model

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace TLAPI.Models
{
    public class Order
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public int CreatorID { get; set; } = 0; 
    }
}
```

When I try to test this in swagger, either providing a null or empty string its giving me an error.  Not quite sure what I am doing wrong with this syntax.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#datetime-value-generation

Comment: Where do i place this function? In the model or inside dbcontext?